# Scala program that gives me smallest and largest number from an Array

Tags: scala

I am looking for a scala code that gives me new Array that contains the smallest and largest number in myArr.

I am able to write the below code    . How do i write it in a  single function

```
scala> val myArr = Array(1,5,3)
 myArr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 5, 3)

 scala> myArr.reduce((a,b) => if(a>b)a else b)
 res0: Int = 5

 scala> myArr.reduce((a,b) => if(a<b)a else b)
 res1: Int = 1
```

Expected output :  Array(1,5)

Comment: Well, you can just call both. You can also merge the reduce logic of both in a single `foldLeft`, you can also use the built-in `min` and `max` functions, you may also use recursion or a while loop.

Comment: I just want to try without using min and max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val myArr = Array(1,5,3)

val result = myArr.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){
 case (min :: max :: _, value) if value < min => List(value, max) // lower than the minimun
 case (min :: max :: _, value) if value > max => List(min, value) // greater than the maximun
 case (Nil, value) => List(value, value) // first value
 case (l, _) => l // the final list doesn't need to be updated
}
```

you can check it here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XLE8VAKTRhWbl0JFrjGgnw
It uses the list to have better pattern matching.

Comment: what is case (min :: max :: _, value), what is ::

Comment: it decomposes the list expecting at least two elements and assigns the first to the min, and the second to the max value. The `::`  is to split the elements of the list, the latest `:: _` means "and the rest of the list" that will be the Nil value of the empty list.